# How to replace all matching substrings in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to replace all matching substring from all documents in a collection.

```
{ "content": "This is sample [/article] content.This is sample [/article] content." }
```

`[/article]` substring needs to be replaced with `[/getting-started]`.

I have tried with the below code but it replaces only the first matches of string

```
 db.versions.find({}).forEach(function(e,i) {
    e.content=e.content.replace("/article1]","/getting-started]");
    db.versions.save(e);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use replace regex matches as following

```
db.versions.find({}).forEach(function(e,i) {
    e.content=e.content.replace(/article\]/g,"getting-started]");
    db.versions.save(e);
});
```

result:

> This is sample [/getting-started] content.This is sample
>   [/getting-started] content.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed, It works perfectly. If you have any documentation link for mongdb query.js, please share the link.

Answer (score 2):

Try the power of regex to run through the document till end

```
db.versions.find({}).forEach(function(e,i) {
    var find = "//article";
    var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
    e.content = e.content.replace(re,"//getting-started");
    db.versions.save(e);
});
```